# How to improve element selector?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3

How can I improve this selector?

```
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
"//*[@id=\"nav-flyout-shopAll\"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[4]/span[1]"
));
```

Thanks

```
package SelenuimSession;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

/**
 * 
 * @author ASHUTOSH SINGH
 *
 */

public class AmazonClick {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
      "C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");

   WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-shopall"));
   WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-flyout-
                               shopAll\"]/div[2]/span[1]/span"));
   performClick(ele,ele1,driver);
}

/**
 * The below method was created for general purpose utility to pass the params as well as          
 *  the driver 
 * @param ele
 * @param ele1
 * @param driver
 */
public static void performClick(WebElement ele,WebElement ele1,WebDriver driver) {
    Actions act=new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(ele).perform();
    act.moveToElement(ele1).perform();

    WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-flyout-
                         shopAll\"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[4]/span[1]"));
    ele2.click();
    }   
}
```

DOM:

```
<div id="nav-flyout-shopAll" class="nav-catFlyout nav-flyout" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 57px; left: 192px;">
    <div class="nav-arrow" style="position: absolute; left: 74.6719px;">
        <div class="nav-arrow-inner"></div>
    </div>
<div class="nav-template nav-flyout-content nav-tpl-itemList">
    <span class="nav-hasPanel nav-item" data-nav-panelkey="EchoPanel" role="navigation" aria-label="Echo &amp; Alexa">
        <span class="nav-text">Echo &amp; Alexa</span>
```

Comment: What is your goal, the DOM, and the error you are receiving?

Comment: paste the html snippet of the webelement that you are trying to find.

Comment: <div id="nav-flyout-shopAll" class="nav-catFlyout nav-flyout" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 57px; left: 192px;"><div class="nav-arrow" style="position: absolute; left: 74.6719px;"><div class="nav-arrow-inner"></div></div><div class="nav-template nav-flyout-content nav-tpl-itemList">                            <span class="nav-hasPanel                              nav-item" data-nav-panelkey="EchoPanel" role="navigation" aria-label="Echo &amp; Alexa">                    <span class="nav-text">Echo &amp; Alexa</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the element "Echo Spot" from the Amazon.in page.

```
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//* 
[text()='Echo Spot']"));
```